# A non-exponential proof of $\lim_{x \to \infty} c^{1/x} = 1$ when $c>1$

Tags: real-analysis

My textbook asks me to prove this when we are just beginning to learn limits.

$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} c^{1/x} = 1, \  \ \ \ \ c>1$

> Suppose otherwise,
>
> $$\forall N > 0, \exists x, \epsilon \ | \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x> N \ \ \ \ \
>  \Rightarrow \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ c^{1/x} \geq 1 + \epsilon $$
>
> $$ \begin{equation} \begin{split} &c \geq (1 + \epsilon)^x \ \ \ \ \ \
>  \ \ \ &&\text{since $c>0$ } \\  &c \geq (1 + \epsilon)^N \ \ \ \ \ \ \
>  \ \ &&\text{since $c^{x} > c^{N}$}  
> \end{split} \end{equation}$$

Now this is obviously false, but I do not know how would you would prove it without a proof relying on a exponential function.

The best I could come up with is this:

> Prove that for any $x,y > 1$ where $y > x$, there exists some $N$ such
>   that $x^N > y$.
>
> For any such $y$, there exists $z > y$. Let $x^N = y$. But again, this
>   assumes that such an $N$ exists.

**Could you suggest alternative ways of proving this? Or do you think that what I've done is satisfactory?**

Comment: What you write after "Suppose otherwise" is not the negation of limit $1$

Comment: When you are just beginning to learn limits, I am interested in how you define $c^{1/x}$ for arbitrary positive $x$ (or is your $x$ only running over the naturals?)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen We haven't, which is part of the problem I think

Comment: I think it's safe to assume it is running over the naturals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I shall assume that we are taking the limit only over natrual $x$, i.e., we can write it more suggestively as
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}c^{1/n}.$$
I shall also assume that you define $c^{1/n}$ as the unique positive real number $y$ such that $c=y^n$ (where the latter is just the product of $n$ identical factors).
As $0<y\le1$ implies $y^n\le1$, we conclude that $c^{1/n}>1$ for our $c>1$

Let $\epsilon>0$. We want to find $N$ such that $|c^{1/n}-1|<\epsilon$ for all $n>N$. 
By the archimedean property of the real numbers, there exists $N\in\Bbb N$ with $N>\frac c\epsilon$. 
Then we find that for all $n>N$, by the Bernoulli inequality,
$$ (1+\epsilon)^n\ge 1+n\epsilon>1+N\epsilon>1+c>c$$
and hence $1+\epsilon>c^{1/n}>1$ and ultimately $|c^{1/n}-1|<\epsilon$. (Note that we used $0<a<b\implies a^n<b^n$ somewhere along the way)

Answer (score 0):

$$c^{1/x}$$ is a decreasing function of $x$, and it is bounded below (at least by $0$). So it converges.

Now if the limit is $L$,

$$L=\lim_{x\to\infty}c^{1/x}$$ implies $$L^2=\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}c^{1/x}\right)^2=\lim_{x\to\infty}c^{2/x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}c^{1/x}=L.$$